# How to execute a ready-made Windows Run command

Tags: c#, winforms, shell, process.start

I need to start the default mail client using the command line received from windows registry. How to do it in C# ?
Process.Start cannot execute the whole line, it needs to be split, but i dont known what it will be

I get a line to run for example here in registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\Microsoft Outlook\shell\open\command
```

How to run this command line with c# ?

```
"C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle
```

More complex example

```
%systemRoot%\system32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\hmmapi.dll",OpenInboxHandler
```

Comment: Take what is between `""` as the process and the rest as command-line arguments.

Comment: maybe there is a more elegant way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/3110834

Comment: Thanks, the issue is resolved, the /C option was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved!
To execute an arbitrary shell command, you need to specify the /C parameter for cmd.exe

```
public static void ExecuteShellCommand(string command)
{
    var ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + command)
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = true
    };
    Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did so

```
string[] lines = cmd.Split('"');
if (lines.Length > 1)
{
    ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo(lines[1].Trim());
    process.UseShellExecute = true;
    if (lines.Length > 2)
        process.Arguments = lines[2].Trim();
    Process.Start(process);
}
```

but don't eat it

```
%systemRoot%\system32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\hmmapi.dll",OpenInboxHandler
```

Comment: If the command line has quotes in the arguments, this will not work. It works for the Outlook command line you found, but you can't be certain that some other client that's been set as the default won't have a quote in the arguments. What Reza Aghaei suggested is a more robust way to do it.

Comment: ^Not to mention this will also grab what is in between the double quotes (`"`) , so `lines[2].Trim()` will most likely be `string.Empty`